# What is the fundamental shape used for enclosing a 4-dimentional object?

Tags: manifolds

In 2-dimensions, any enclosed space can be approximately represented with line-segments composed of the space between 2 points.

In 3-dimensions, any enclosed space can be approximately represented with triangles composed of the space between 3 points.

When working in 4-dimensions, what shape can serve the same role for approximately enclosing a space?

[image]

Comment: There is a general family of convex shapes.  The convex hull of $n+1$ points can give us an $n$-dimensional "volume" called an $n$-simplex.